# ASP .NET MVC + Submit + JSON

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, ajax, json

I need to send Model data and JSON data in one request. What does it mean:

If i send JSON data with this function:

```
    $("#SaveOrder").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Manager/AddOrder',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: $.toJSON(ResultArray),
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
        });
    });
```

i have

`public ActionResult AddOrder(SUPNew.Models.Order newOrder, List<OrderList> ResultArray)`

```
SUPNew.Models.Order newOrder = null  
List<OrderList> ResultArray = not null
```

but if i send request with `<input type="submit">` i have

```
SUPNew.Models.Order newOrder = not null  
List<OrderList> ResultArray = null
```

How can i send jQuery array (JSON data) and SUPNew.Models.Order in one request?

---

Content of ResultArray- $.toJSON(ResultArray), where ResultArray is jQuery array like:

```
var CurrentOrder =
            [{
                'ProviderAn': $("#DdlProviders").val(),
                'ItemAn': $("#DdlItems").val()
            }];
```

And this is MVC 2

Comment: What is the content of ResultArray? And is this MVC 3?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't forget to set the request content type:

```
$('#SaveOrder').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Manager/AddOrder',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify({
            newOrder: { orderProp1: 'value1', orderProp2: 'value2' },
            resultArray: [
                { orderListProp1: 'value1', orderListProp2: 'value2' },
                { orderListProp1: 'value3', orderListProp2: 'value4' },
                { orderListProp1: 'value5', orderListProp2: 'value6' }
            ]
        }),
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function(result) {
            // the request succeeded
        }
    });

    // Don't forget to cancel the default action or if SaveOrder
    // is some link you might get redirected before the 
    // AJAX call ever had time to execute
    return false;
});
```

Now on the server side you might need a new view model which will aggregate those two objects:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public Order NewOrder { get; set; }
    public List<OrderList> ResultArray { get; set; }
}
```

and have:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddOrder(MyViewModel model)
{
    ...
}
```

Also on the server side unless you are using ASP.NET 3.0 which supports JSON by default you need to write a [custom handler capable of parsing it](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/15/sending-json-to-an-asp-net-mvc-action-method-argument.aspx).

---

UPDATE:

You could use [the following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/serialize-form-to-json-with-jquery/1186309#1186309) to serialize the form as JSON:

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function()
{
    var o = {};
    var a = this.serializeArray();
    $.each(a, function() {
        if (o[this.name]) {
            if (!o[this.name].push) {
                o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
            }
            o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
        } else {
            o[this.name] = this.value || '';
        }
    });
    return o;
};
```

and then:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Manager/AddOrder',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify({
        newOrder: $('#SaveOrder').serializeObject(),
        resultArray: [
            { orderListProp1: 'value1', orderListProp2: 'value2' },
            { orderListProp1: 'value3', orderListProp2: 'value4' },
            { orderListProp1: 'value5', orderListProp2: 'value6' }
        ]
    }),
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
});
```

Comment: @user568262, in my answer I suggested using a view model (`MyViewModel`) which will aggregate both `NewOrder` and `ResultArray` properties and send them as a single JSON object. You could assign the `NewOrder` property using `form.serialize()` and leave the `ResultArray` property as in my example. Isn't this working for you?

Comment: I tried for fake value like { ClientFIO : 'Hello' } and it works for form values and bind into "Order NewOrder". Now just need to find nice plugin for form->json data serialize and it should work. I hope :)

Comment: @user568262, please see if the proposed technique in my update works for you.

Comment: Yeah, i found this serialize 5 min ago and was tring to make it work, but ur example didn't give any chance for mistake. It's awsome, u r my Guru :) Everything work perfect. Sorry, didn't watch very careful at ur first post.

Comment: Just one little problem. It isn't work RedirectToAction("Index") in AddOrder Action =\

Comment: Is it any way without                     complete: function (data) {
                        window.location.replace("/Manager");
                    } ?